# How to remove a text in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game in pygame which has some buttons and on every button pressed a text is displayed on screen on same position (co-ordinates) but the text is overlapping each other.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should, more often than not, clear the entire screen at the beginning of every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill in the screen with for example a background image or just white color to erase the old text before writing the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided x and y coordinates to display your text like in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-display-text-to-pygame-window/

Then the thing you can do is make a **variable** that saves the coordinates where your text is displayed.

When you display your **first message on the screen**, simply **add some value** in that **variable** (in the y-axis if your message is displayed vertically) and the **second message** that will **display** will be going to be at the b**ottom of the previous message**.

```py
size = [800,600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
black = pygame.color.Color('#000000')
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 40)
text1 = font.render('YOUR MESSAGE1', False, black)
text2 = font.render('MESSAGE2', False, black)

#Center
coordinates = (size[0]//2, size[1]//2)


window.fill(white)

window.blit(text, coordinates)
coordiantes = (coordiantes[0] ,coordiantes[1] +5 )#This 5 is the extra addition to y axis
window.blit(text, coordinates) #this will print below 5 pixel from previous message
```

You can also make a function or class

```py
def setCoordinates(coordinates):
    coordinates = (coordiantes[0] ,coordiantes[1] +5)
    return coordinates
```

Use this function as

```py
coordinates = (100,200)
coordinates = setCoordinates(coordinates) 
print(coordinates)
```

Output

```
(100,205)
```

Again calling the function gives

```py
coordinates = setCoordinates(coordinates) 
print(coordinates)
```

Output

```
(100,210)
```

Hopefully, You get what you want from this post :)